# WSO2 IS 5.7 editUserStore with soap web service is not working

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to edit user store using spring boot web service using soap web service given by wso2. But unable to edit user store in wso2. currently, I am using WSO2 IS 5.7

This is the error I'm getting

```
<soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">UniqueID property is not provided.</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason>
```

This is soap request that i am sending to edit the user store

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.configuration.store.user.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <xsd:editUserStore>
        <xsd:userStoreDTO>
            <xsd1:className>##LDAP_CLASS##</xsd1:className>
            <xsd1:description>##DESCRIPTION##</xsd1:description>
            <xsd1:disabled>false</xsd1:disabled>
            <xsd1:domainId>##DOMAIN_NAME##</xsd1:domainId>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>ConnectionName</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##CONNECTION_NAME##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>ConnectionURL</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##CONNECTION_URL##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>ConnectionPassword</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##PASSWORD##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>UserSearchBase</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##USER_SEARCH_BASE##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>UserEntryObjectClass</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##USER_ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>GroupEntryObjectClass</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##GROUP_ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>UserNameAttribute</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>UserNameSearchFilter</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##USER_NAME_SEARCH_FILTER##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
            <xsd1:properties>
                <xsd1:name>UserNameListFilter</xsd1:name>
                <xsd1:value>##USER_NAME_LIST_FILTER##</xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:properties>
        </xsd:userStoreDTO>
         </xsd:editUserStore>
```

Comment: This is my editUserStore.xml file

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: There is no error  actually i am getting . but in response there is one line is come    that is <soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">UniqueID property is not provided.</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason>

Comment: can you share the soap request you are sending

Comment: yah sure i a sharing with you wait

Comment: <soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">UniqueID property is not provided.</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason>

Comment: ok, this is the response. but, what is the request which you are sending to the WSO2 identity server?

Comment: you can edit the question itself and add the request response pair

Comment: sajith i have added the soap request pls see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you are not sending the `UniqueID` property in the `editUserStore` request.

To retrieve the `UniqueID` for each of the user stores, you can use the following request. This will list all the user stores with their properties and you can find the `UniqueID` for each of them.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:getSecondaryRealmConfigurations/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then, you can avoid this error by adding `UniqueID` property to the `editUserStore` request as follows.

```
    <xsd1:properties>
        <xsd1:name>UniqueID</xsd1:name>
        <xsd1:value>751d3a55-5eb3-462b-ad6a-c93fcc444927</xsd1:value>
    </xsd1:properties>
```

PS: These admin services are available in the [`UserStoreConfigAdminService`](https://localhost:9443/services/UserStoreConfigAdminService?wsdl)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Sajith. I am going to try this.